# How to get Outbound email similar features in Web 8 for new license?

Tags: web8, outbound-email

It says [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-B3F1B26B-E302-41C9-8211-5A76AE669A7F) that outbound email is completely deprecated.
Is there any alternate solution that is offered instead. We have a new client that is interested in mailing and distribution, tracking. Can we expect this soon or is there a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge there is no such community free version is available - but you may think of integrating with many paid third party options like - Pardot, Salesforce etc.

On the other side, the deprecated means you can still use it in current release (Web 8) on Premise but it may get dropped from Next release - So you can still use it in Web 8, however definitely considering the future it is **not recommended**.

Moreover, if you are planning to have SDL Web Cloud, then deprecated actually mostly means dropped.

Comment: Thanks @PankajGaur for your feedback. Even though Outbound Email still works with Web 8, SDL does not offer OE license for new customers. So the above question was more in terms of new customers. If OE related services (Mailer, Bounce Processor, etc.) are not installed/running on the CMS server then how is the email generation handled? Once the emails are generated, delivering the emails is relatively easier.

Comment: yeah that makes sense of not giving licenses for new customer for deprecated stuff :(

Comment: It still doesn't answer my query regarding email generation. Is the Mailer service now bundled with Audience Manager (so can be licensed for new customers)?

Comment: No it does not, as far as I know

Comment: SDL won't give you a license for a product that will be discontinued - this makes perfect sense. However, you should be able to run it anyway, it's available in the installer if you use the LEGACY switch.

Comment: @NunoLinhares sorry for asking the same thing again. If OE related services (Mailer is the one I am most concerned about) are not installed on the CMS box, how would the email generation be one? Would we still be managing pages as "Email contents"? How would the contents of these pages translate into .eml files which are currently generated by the Mailer service.

Comment: You need OE services for this.